# UIScrollView zoom issue with UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, scrollview

I have a scroll view which shows a image view. I am trying to handle UIRotationGestureRecognizer on the image view. I get the event for rotation and apply the required transform on the same. The image gets properly rotated in the scroll view. Then when I do any operations in the scroll view like zoom or pan the image rotation and position goes for a toss

_mainView is the subView of UIScrollView which is also used for zooming

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture=[[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationGesture:)];    
[_mainView addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];    
[rotationGesture release];

-(void) rotationGesture:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) sender {    
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || 
       sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(sender.view.transform, 
                                                            sender.rotation);
        _currRotation = _currRotation + sender.rotation;
        [sender setRotation:0];
    }
}
```

I will like to understand what would be the right way to handling rotation with-in the scroll view and it maintains that rotation even after zoom events in Scroll View.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the [gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) method in your UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, and return all gestures you want to recognize *simultaneously*.  If you still have trouble with it, check out the answers to [UIImageView Gestures (Zoom, Rotate) Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448614/uiimageview-gestures-zoom-rotate-question).

Good luck!

EDIT: Your comment has me guessing that the issue is that you can only have one transform on at a time, and the scroll view applies a scale transform, replacing the rotation one.  You could remove the native zoom recognizer (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539148/ios-can-i-override-pinch-in-out-behavior-of-uiscrollview)), or nest another UIView in the scroll view, and apply the rotation transform to that.  I like option two, it seems easier.  If you go with option one, use CGAffineTransformConcat to apply both the zoom and rotate transformations independently.

Comment: Thanks, I have already added the same. The problem is not with the Gesture recogniser. The main problem is once the rotation happens and the if I scroll or zoom the rotation goes for a toss and the image is no longer aligned properly in the scroll view